# Comment-Reply structure of wordpress in php

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, blogs

Hey all i would like to ask that i want to show the comment system like wordpress in my php blog management page.
How could i manage this?
I have a table that stores comments, and another table that stores reply. 
Reply table has field of parent_reply_id and comment_id.
I can list all the reply on comment base but if any reply has parent_reply_id than it is not showed below that reply....

I hope you guys got my question.

Comment: Hi what this parent_replay_id means this is something like replay to some other replay of the comment?If you don't need this then don't map this in the query. use your query like this  SELECT * FROM replay_table WHERE comment_id = $id

Comment: Yeah parent_reply_id is meant for reply to another reply. Thats why i need this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this
    /*You get all replay with comment id*/

```
$replay_sql = mysql_query("Select * From replay_table where comment_id=$id");
while($result = mysql_fetch_row($replay_sql)){
```

/*You get all replay to any other replay*/

```
$replay_to_replay = mysql_query(SELECT * FROM replay_table WHERE parent_replay_id = $result['id']);
}
```

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: Dear i have done this all. but i am confused how to display all the reply and reply to reply just like nested reply...